# How do I pass document.getElementById("someid") on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am sorry, I am new to JavaScript.

I want to pass an id selector as a parameter on click event as follows:

I tried:

```
<button onclick="mycustomfunction(document.getElementById('someTextId'))"/>
```

and using jQuery:

```
<button onclick="mycustomfunction($('#someTextId').val())"/> 


mycustomfunction(control)
{
// do something with the control
}
```

Can someone please help me to understand where I am going wrong?

Comment: Why not just get the id within the function?

Comment: Why do you need to pass this value to the function when it can just as easily be evaluated in the function since the value does not correlate to the element actually being clicked?

Comment: You are passing an element not an ID, also you are missing `function` keyword.

Comment: I don't see any problem with your first example: http://jsfiddle.net/CP3cC/ (assuming the missing `function` is just a typo. If not, learn the JavaScript basics first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/learn/javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do the `document.getElementById()` call inside the event handler function and pass in the id string

```
<button onclick="mycustomfunction('someTextId')"/> 

function mycustomfunction(controlId) {
    var control = document.getElementById(controlId);

    // now work with control
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`<button onclick="mycustomfunction($('#someTextId').val())"/>` - this will pass the value. You end up with a string.

`<button onclick="mycustomfunction(document.getElementById('someTextId'))"/>` - this will pass an object reverence to the DOM element. From here you could do:

```
mycustomfunction(element) {
    alert(element.value)
}
```

Comment: It executes during the actual event, not page load.

Answer (score 1):

The value you are trying to get has nothing to do with the button being pushed.  Just remove that reference from the button altogether and do like this:

```
<button onclick="mycustomfunction()"/> 
<script>
function myscustomfunction() {
    var val = $('#someTextId').val(); // must be an input field for val() to work otherwise use html() or text()
    // do other stuff
}
</script>
```

Or if you really want to make it more jQuery friendly:

```
<button id="cool_button" /> 
<script>
$('#cool_button').click(function() {
    var val = $('#someTextId').val(); // must be an input field for val() to work otherwise use html() or text()
    // do other stuff
});
</script>
```

You will find that one of the nice things about jQuery, when done properly, is that you can begin removing the event handler logic from the HTML structure.

Comment: I am actually calling this in a for loop, so the parameter has the index, so I have to use this technique